# Brahman versus Ishvara for the 5 or 6 main forms

Tags: shiva, vishnu, shakti, surya, ganapati

Vishnu, Shiva, Ambika, Ganapati, Skanda, and Surya are five forms of Brahman or Ishvara. If they're five forms of Ishvara how can they marry, start famillies with themselves?

Comment: That's a [smart(a)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition) question.

Comment: What? How can they marry with each other. What do u mean by that.

Comment: @SinghS1 Shiv-Shakti.

Comment: @Haridasa its not a topic for smatra. A smarta consider nurguna as supreme. And there is difference between Isvara and and Tridev-Tridevi. All 3 tridev are one. It's one taking 3 different roles. Similarly tridevi are one. And shiv-shakti. Then both are one not 2. The One divede itself in 2. Shi-shakti separated for jagat kalyaan. And took human form as rudra-parvati. Marriage is considered union b=w two. They married and again become one. We call it there leele. They dont need human path to produce child.

Comment: We all are there child. As this universe iz ths product of Purusha and Prakriti.